# HTML - Change form position

Tags: html

How do I change the position of this form, with an absolute position?

```html
<form id="contact_form" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="row">
  <label for="name">Jouw naam:</label><br />
  <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <label for="email">Jouw email:</label><br />
  <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <label for="message">Jouw bericht:</label><br />
  <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
 </div>
 <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a css selector by selecting the form id of `contact_form` and adding a rule for positon

```html
<style>
  #contact_form {
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>

<form id="contact_form" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="row">
  <label for="name">Jouw naam:</label><br />
  <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <label for="email">Jouw email:</label><br />
  <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" /><br />
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <label for="message">Jouw bericht:</label><br />
  <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br />
 </div>
 <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send email" />
</form>
```